# creating workflow string doesn't resolve correctly

Tags: designer-workflow

in a workflow I am setting a local variable to the value of 2 parameters - one from the current list (works) and one from a field populated via the collect data from user task.  Each time I've done this, it concatenates the actual text of the formula instead of retrieving the data! I've checked the lookup several times, and it repro's every time.

[image]

here it shows the output from above

[image]

here is where I changed the workflow to try and workaround it by first setting a local variable to the collect data info but it just marginally improved matters by adding the "Build3" which is all I wanted, but then again adding the reference after.  There's no way to out of the box extract what comes before the "[" so again I'm stuck.

Comment: The variable "Final Build Folder" is a column value?

Answer (score 1):

This is the syntax of a variable with column content. You can not copy and paste that syntax elsewhere.

Do the following:

- The SPD click the variable, if it not be selected as a whole, if you can delete a single character, is that she is wrong.
- Delete the variable and use the "Add or Change Lookup" to select the column that should have its value printed on the string.

Comment: Yes I did this. it CHANGES it to a text string when you compile!

Comment: Strange, because the symptoms you wrote are a corrupted variable.